# Jetpack Compose's AnimatedVisibility within parent composable's layout bounds

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I have two `Box` as my composables, one outer `Box` and one inner `Box`. I am trying to animate the visibility of the inner `Box` with a simple slide in/out horizontally.

```
var isVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

Button(onClick = { isVisible = !isVisible }) { Text("Click") }

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(300.dp)
        .height(16.dp)
        .background(Color.Blue.copy(alpha = 0.5F))
    ) {
                androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility(
                    visible = isVisible,
                    enter = slideInHorizontally(),
                    exit = slideOutHorizontally(),
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(100.dp)
                            .height(16.dp)
                            .background(Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.5F))
                    )
                }
            }
```

Currently when animated, the inner box will slide beyond the boundaries of the outer boxes's width of `300dp`. Is there a way to prevent that from happening, or do I need to utilize lower level animation APIs?

The current default implementation for `slideInHorizontally()` is

```
animationSpec: FiniteAnimationSpec<IntOffset> =
        spring(
            stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow,
            visibilityThreshold = IntOffset.VisibilityThreshold
        ),
    initialOffsetX: (fullWidth: Int) -> Int = { -it / 2 },
```

I attempted to overwrite `initialOffsetX` to just `fullWidth`, though that only resulted in the animation completely animate the full width of the layout, and does not solve the issue that the inner box still animates beyond the parent box's layout boundaries.